# Will using Session Object for cache is good?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, caching

Hope everything is fine.

I have encountered a project where the earlier developer was using session object for cache mechanism in ASP.Web Project.

So, He used to save some objects in the session and retrieve them for many reasons to do many functions like pagination, binding Grid after one row got affected.

I understand that session will expire once the user log out

will changing the code to have fresh data every time affect performance ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using cookie if you are so afraid? Also the way you are talking about cache it create a mistake somehow, there are numbers of caching you need to specifically say which one, there are some cache that you even use a stand alone database for.

Comment: No He was using session to cache, for example, in page load he get data and save it in session Sesssio["A"] = A, then in assign the data to grid, now in page_index change event he get the data from the cache and assign it the grid, like saving database round trip. But this is not the purpose of session

Comment: `will changing the code to have fresh data every time affect performance ?` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: you should not store cache data in the `Session` object. This is very bad practice. Use the built in cache mechanisms. They are much better and offer functionalities like cache location which you won't be able to have with session

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASP.NET Session consumes server memory (unless it is saved/restored to a database on every request). While it increases a page performance, note that your server handles requests from different users. If you store rather large data in Session for every user, this consumes a lot of server memory that causes memory shortage.

I recommend you find a balance between saving data in memory and loading it from a database on every page request. For example, short and rarely modified data set can be stored in Session. Never store large data sets in Session. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Qn: Will changing the code to have fresh data every time affect performance ?
Ans: Generally, yes. because each time you need the data, it fetches from the true source again. it will definitely affect performance compared to directly getting from session memory.

**Food for thought:**
Using session to store key data is useful and it depends on how and when you use it. Using it correctly gets the job done effectively and efficiently - why not, while using it wrongly screws things up including performance degradation when your concurrent users are in large numbers! Caching is also a huge topic on its own :)

Comment: This is a great answer, this is the thing. I think he was using it wrongly. Which causes the problem to happen.